# Multiplying from 1 to 100, why is there a negative number for the 17th time？

Tags: scala, for-loop

Multiplying from 1 to 100, why is there a negative number for the 17th time？

```
object Accumulate {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var num = 1
    for (a <- 1 to 100) {
      num = a * num
      println("Result：" + num + ", Time:" + a)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Integer overflow

Comment: Integer overflow? `13! == 6227020800` exceeds `2**32 - 1 == 4294967295` which is maximum `uint` value

Comment: What is the type of `num`?  What is the largest positive value for that type?  What is the actual value of `factorial(17)`?  (Or as a mathematician would write it `17!`)

Comment: Now is Int. Which type should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, it has already been explained that what is happing is just an overflow of the `Int` data type. An implementation detail of the underlying hardware which is unable to represent a bigger number using the assigned amount of memory for that variable.

Thus you ask:

> Which type should I use?

You may first try a `Long` to see how far it goes:

```scala
var num: Long = 1L
for (i <- 1 to 100) {
  val previousResult = num
  num = num * i
  if num < 0 then
    println(s"(Long) Fail at iteration: ${i} last valid result was: ${previousResult}")
    return
}
println(s"(Long) Success, result: ${num}")
```

Which will fail at iteration `21` and the previous valid value would be something pretty big: `2432902008176640000`

Thus, we would need to use something that is able to hold values infinitely large; that is `BigInt`

```scala
var num = BigInt(1)
for (i <- 1 to 100) {
  val previousResult = num
  num = num * i
  if num < 0 then
    println(s"(BigInt) Fail at iteration: ${i} last valid result was: ${previousResult}")
    return
}
println(s"(BigInt) Success, result: ${num}")
```

This will succeed with a resulting value of incredible magnitude:
`93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000`

---

BTW, since it seems you are new to the language let me suggest that there is no need to use mutable variables to solve a problem trivial like this:

```scala
val result = (1 to 100).foldLeft(BigInt(1))(_ * _)
```

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/SkvTB7ESSq6sEjej2TcNeQ/6)*.

Answer (score -1):

Type is Int default on Scala. You can try a big one than an Int type.

Comment: Maybe explain in the answer why `Int` is not good :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer].